# Random one-hot matrix in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make a matrix `x` with shape `(n_samples, n_classes)` where each `x[i]` is a random one-hot vector. Here's a slow implementation:

```
x = np.zeros((n_samples, n_classes))
J = np.random.choice(n_classes, n_samples)
for i, j in enumerate(J):
    x[i, j] = 1
```

What's a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create an identity matrix using `np.eye`:

```
x = np.eye(n_classes)
```

Then use `np.random.choice` to select rows at random:

```
x[np.random.choice(x.shape[0], size=n_samples)]
```

As a shorthand, just use:

```
np.eye(n_classes)[np.random.choice(n_classes, n_samples)]
```

Demo:

```
In [90]: np.eye(5)[np.random.choice(5, 100)]
Out[90]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       .... (... to 100)
```

Answer (score 4):

For the assignment part, you can use [*advanced indexing*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
# initialize data
n_samples = 3
n_classes = 5
x = np.zeros((n_samples, n_classes))
J = np.random.choice(n_classes, n_samples)

# assign with advanced indexing
x[np.arange(n_samples), J] = 1

x
#array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

Or another option, use [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) from `sklearn`:

```
n_samples = 3
n_classes = 5
J = np.random.choice(n_classes, n_samples)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(n_values=n_classes, sparse=False)
enc.fit_transform(J.reshape(-1,1))

#array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
#       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```